# GNU make: what difference between eval funciton and expand variable into makefile directly

Tags: makefile, eval

the Makefile define a multi-line variable, which define a rule, reference it by eval function work fine:

```
define a
b: 
        echo b
endef

$(eval $(a))
```

excute result:

```
$ make 
echo b 
b
```

but failed if reference variable directly:

```
define a :=
b: 
        echo b
endef

$(a)
```

execute make will fail:

make: *** No rule to make target 'echo', needed by 'b'.  Stop.

but if I write rule in one line, that will work:

```
define a :=
b: ; echo b
endef

$(a)
```

make is ok:

```
$ make
echo b
b
```

why multi-line variable we need eval function, what GNU make do when expand variable into makefile directly.

I found not material about this in the whole GNU make manual.

Comment: You're trying to expand a variable in a context where its value is interpreted only as a list of words, separated by spaces, tabs or newlines. The result (`b: echo b`) is then parsed as make syntax... The `eval` function has a different interpretation of its arguments, where spaces, tabs and newlines are not treaded only as word separators. If you really want to use this very strange style (which I would not recommend), add a semi-column at the end of the first line of your multi-line variable definition (`b:;\n\techo b`).

Comment: Coincidentally I just updated the GNU make manual with some more details of this; consider http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/make.git/tree/doc/make.texi#n1585 and see if that makes things any clearer.

Comment: @MadScientist the new section clear the use scenario. but `make does not re-split lines after it has expanded` is a little confusing. when make read a multi-line define, it delete all newlines? if no, it can write it directly with newlines, no need re-split. the newlines are deleted by which stage ?

Comment: It doesn't delete them per se, it treats them like any other whitespace.  They don't have any special meaning such as "end of a line" etc.  They're just treated like spaces.  The new docs mention this.